# Function $f(t) - kf(1-t) = t$ . Rearrange and find the formula for f(t)

Tags: functions

[Click here to see the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV7dz.png)

So for question 2 (ii a), if i say from (i), we know the identity cannot hold when k is + or- 1. Therefore for (*), the equation cannot be valid thus there is no solution. Is it a reasonable answer?

For (c), I tried to expand the $(2t-1)^3$ to $8t^3-12t^2+6t-1$ but then I do not know how to continue.

Comment: No, it is not a reasonable answer. Case (ii) deals with the only cases that case (i) does NOT deal with.

Comment: Yes, but for (ii) the product is g(x). If we let g(x) equals to (t) then the equation will be contradictory to the first identity ? so it cannot be valid?

Comment: No, it would not be contradictory to (i) because (i) assumes explicitly that $k\neq \pm 1$, and now you are explicitly dealing with the situation where $k=1$, right? Think of it this way: (i) Deals with everything but red cars. Now you come along with a red car. Sorry, but (i) can't help you if you have a red car.

Comment: ok I get it. But how would you go about proving it?

Answer (score 0):

To prove ii)a

$f({1\over2})-f({1\over2})={1\over2}$ contradiction. You should be able to figure out b) based on this.

For c)

Let $f(t)=at^3+bt^2+ct+d$

Then $f(1-t)=-at^3+(b+3a)t^2+(-3a-2b-c)t+(a+b+c+d)$

So $2a=8,-3a=-12,2c+2b+3a=6,-a-b-c=-1$

So $a=4,b+c=-3,d=$anything will work.